# Why the numerical values of $\int\limits_{-a}^{a} e^{-x^{e}}\ \text{d}x $ are not real?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, transcendental-numbers, error-function

I have tried to know more about behavior of function which has the similar form of error function where the power is not integer as shown with the below integral , The below integral is converge and has a closed form defined by incomplet Gamma function as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral(+e%5E((-x%5E(e))))) , The value of the integral over positive real line is equal to $\frac 1 e \Gamma(\frac 1 e)$ ,The problem that i have accrossed this integral produces [complex numerical values](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral(+e%5E((-x%5E(e)))),+x%3D+-0.5+to+4) converse to error function . Then My question here is :

Why the numerical values of $\displaystyle\int\limits_{-a}^{a} e^{-x^{e}}\ \text{d}x $ are not real ? or it has real values only if the power of $x$ is a positive integer ?.

**Note:** $a$ is a real number

Comment: Can't it be because $x^e$ for $x<0$ is complex?

Comment: Is there any "physical reality" associated to this integral ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is $\exp(-x^e)$.  First the real part, then the imaginary part.

[image: re] [image: im]

Since the imaginary part looks like that, we can see that the imaginary part of $\int_{-1}^{1} \exp(-x^e)\;dx$ is negative.